# When connecting, client.connect() returns 0

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I'm using an arduino UNO with ethernet shield. When following a few guides online for a school project I came across this issue. First code sample:

```c
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <Ethernet.h>
     
    EthernetClient client;
     
    byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
    IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 25);
    byte server[] = { 64, 233, 187, 99 }; // Google

    void setup() {  
      Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
    }
     
    void loop() {
      if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
        Serial.println("connected");
        client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
        client.println();
      } else {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
        Serial.println(client.connect(server, 80));
      }
    }
```

This doesn't work, unfortunately. We successfully connect to our network, but `client.connect()` doesn't work and returns 0. Expected result:

> SUCCESS: 1
> TIMED_OUT: -1
> INVALID_SERVER: -2
> TRUNCATED: -3
> INVALID_RESPONSE: -4

According to the documentation it shouldn't be able to return this. Why wouldn't this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dosen't work` is not very useful because it does not describe the observed behavior ... what were you expecting client.connect() to return?

Comment: one of the values specified in the documentation, which would be: 1, -1, -2, -3 or -4.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is wrong. The `connect` function only returns 1 on success and 0 on fail. All examples have `if (client.connect(host, port)) {` (0 is false, 1 is true).

Try the WebClient example provided in the IDE Examples menu for the Ethernet library. It has better diagnostics of Ethernet link.

You can try the WebServer example. It doesn't need Internet connection.

You can try ping the IP address of the Ethernet shield.

The shield should be connected to a router or switch and the gateway IP address should point to a device routing the network traffic to Internet.

Comment: Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:
Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP
connecting to www.google.com...
connection failed

disconnecting.
Received 0 bytes in 0.0000, rate = 0.00 kbytes/second is the response im getting

Comment: this tells us that the shield is detected and the link is active. did you set the IP address and dns server address?

Comment: Yes, I set the ip, dns, and gateway to my own

Comment: To a switch yes. Ping returns 0% loss.

Comment: ok. try the WebServer example. it doesn't need Internet connection

Comment: That works. I can connect to the arduino and it shows a webpage

Comment: in WebClient example change the server to "arduino.cc" and `client.println("GET /asciilogo.txt HTTP/1.1");` as here https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT/blob/a2176889757be3fc3cf9c09a1512081864b39111/examples/Basic/WebClient/WebClient.ino#L57

Comment: That returns connection failed

Comment: use the router's IP address as a gateway. it must be a gateway to Internet

Comment: Using the routers IP as a gateway doesnt fix the problem

Comment: @SimonV., what are the IP settings of your computer? why your network doesn't have DHCP?

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide more than just the IP address. The Arduino also needs to know the default router address in order to send packets to the right place.

Unfortunately there isn't a way of giving it that information without also giving it a DNS address, so you have to do that as well.

You need to have:

```
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress dns(8, 8, 8, 8);
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 25);
```

And then in setup:

```
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dns, gateway);
```

Alternatively you can rely on DHCP to give you all the details, and just use:

```
Ethernet.begin(mac);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not resolve my issue

Comment: I am assuming that your router is 192.168.1.1 - it may not be. You should make sure to use the right IP address there for your network.

Comment: the library defaults to gateway and dns calculated from provided IP (last number changed to 1) and net mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: I have checked and I am indeed using the correct gateway. Would a powerline adapter influence this? I am using the gateway of the powerline adapter I'm connected to.